# How to check if a column exists in apache phoenix?

Tags: java, apache-phoenix

How can we figure out if a column already exists on a table in Apache Phoenix using java?

Answer (score 0):

Normal DB query would be this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYSTEM.CATALOG WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL_NAME';
```

Checking via java (You could get this by running the above query and checking for count as well).

```
public static boolean doesColumnExists(String connectionStr, String tableName, String columnName)
        throws SQLException {
    Connection phoenixConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionStr);
    DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = phoenixConnection.getMetaData();
    ResultSet colResult = databaseMetaData.getColumns("", "", tableName, columnName);
    return colResult.next();
}
```